# Can't deserialize with binaryFormatter after changing namespace of class

Tags: c#, deserialization

After changing the namespace of my class I can no longer deserialize the objects. I've implemented `SerializationBinder`. Example:

```
public class TypeNameConverter : SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        typeName = typeName.Replace("MyOldNamespace", "MyNewNamespace");
        return Type.GetType(string.Format("{0}, {1}", typeName, assemblyName));
    }
}

BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
bf.Binder = new TypeNameConverter();
```

The exception I get is:

> 'System.Runtime.Serialization.TypeLoadExceptionHolder' cannot be converted to type 'MyNewNamespace.MyClass'

Comment: Do you need to change the namespace in the assembly too?

Comment: not exactly sure what you're talking about. all I did was move my dataBase class out of my project and into it's own project. as far as i know the only thing that changed was the namespace.

Answer (score 14):

you forgot to replace the  assembly name:

```
class TypeNameConverter : SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        typeName = typeName.Replace("MyOldNamespace", "MyNewNamespace");
        assemblyName = assemblyName.Replace("MyOldNamespace", "MyNewNamespace");
        return Type.GetType(string.Format("{0}, {1}", typeName, assemblyName));
    }
}
```