# Is it possible to recover data serialized via “BinaryFormatter” after changing field names?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, binaryformatter

After solving the problem of [Is it possible to recover an object serialized via "BinaryFormatter" after changing class names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701481/is-it-possible-to-recover-an-object-serialized-via-binaryformatter-after-chang) I thought this would be also as simple, but spent about half an hour searching for an answer, and it seems it isn't...

Let's say I made a common mistake and declared this in a serializable class

```
public bool Foo {get;set;}
```

And now I want it to be

```
public bool Foo {get {return _foo;} set {_foo = value; OnFooChanged()}}
private bool _foo;
```

Because I need to do something when it's changed.

Can I somehow re-route data from "Foo" into "_foo" when Deserializing, in the same manner I can re-route classes with SerializationBinder?